# how do i measure my internet speed?

Tags: internet, dial-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick way to check my broadband speed.](https://superuser.com/questions/88679/quick-way-to-check-my-broadband-speed)

My internet connection says 920 kb/s. but it doesn't look 920. so how do i measure my real internet speed easily? both uplink and downlink.

Comment: Add at least your operating system as tag.

Comment: Note also, that 920 kb (kilobits) = 115 kB (kilobytes); this is probably the maximum speed which may not be reachable under all circumstances (e.g. if a server is on a slow line or throttles its bandwidth)

Answer (score 6):

[SpeedTest](http://www.speedtest.net/)

Comment: Speedtest is crap. Many modems do on-the-fly compression, and speedtest.net uses very compressible data, leading to massive measurement errors.

Answer (score 2):

[how-to-identify-the-speed-of-my-internet-connection](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/05/how-to-identify-the-speed-of-my-internet-connection/)

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Speed.io](http://www.speed.io/index_en.html)**.