# How to Check the Internet Connection Speed in Windows?

Tags: windows-xp, speed, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quick way to check my broadband speed.](https://superuser.com/questions/88679/quick-way-to-check-my-broadband-speed)

I had internet connection in my home. Its connected by wire with modem(LAN Connection). Now i want to check the internet speed in my system, that means how many kbps comes from my connection?. I want to check that?. Can you please give some useful links?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick way to check my broadband speed.](http://superuser.com/questions/88679/quick-way-to-check-my-broadband-speed) and [how do i measure my internet speed?](http://superuser.com/questions/160817/how-do-i-measure-my-internet-speed-closed)

Comment: Your question was asked already, this is why we are closing it as duplicate. Nothing bad about it though. Welcome to Super User, enjoy your stay around here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.speedtest.net does the job nicely.

Comment: needs flash, which is a huge drawback

Comment: As I commented on a similar posting, Speedtest is not reliable. One time, I had superceded a cap on my data on my connection, so the ISP had cut the speed down to 128k. Speedtest.net consistently told me I had 18m! And when the ISP reinstated my normal speed, Speedtest.net's result didn't change. Either the ISP is gaming the results, or simply Speedtest.net is not accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Speedtest is crap. Seriously. They **consistently** overrate my connection speed by ***15Mbps***.

As near as I can tell, many ISPs (I have Cox Cable internet) use modems that do compression. Speedtest.net appears to use test-data that is highly repetitive.

The end result is they often overestimate your connection's speed by as much as **100%**!

[DSLreports](http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest) and [TestMy.net](http://www.testmy.net/) both use largely incompressible data, and seem far more accurate. I still get a fair bit of variance between their results (and variance between the different types of test), but they're in a far more believable regime than speedtest.net.

Comment: Speedtest works for me but you raise a good point (+1). The correct answer should probably be to try two or more sites to test your speed.

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, I suggest you add your answer to the original one, to keep all possibilities on the same place.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.speedtest.net

> Speedtest.net is a broadband speed analysis tool that allows anyone to test their Internet connection. Ookla provides this service for free to anyone curious about the performance of their connection to and from hundreds of locations around the world. Whether you test just for fun or you really need to certify and validate the true speed of your Internet connectivity, Speedtest.net is the place to be. You can view all of your historical results, share them easily, and even compare them to others in your immediate area or around the globe.