# scriptable internet "speed" test (ping and bandwidth) for Windows

Tags: internet, script, speedtest

I'm familiar with manual internet speed testing using sites like speedtest.net.  I'd like to set something up to automatically run a speed test once per hour 24x7 (for example) on a Windows machine.

Any advice on a tool/approach to do this?

EDIT: Specifically, I'm looking to obtain the same measurements provided with speedtest.net (ping test and bandwidth test) but in an automated fashion I can run in the background.

Comment: Are you looking to test speed or bandwidth? Speedtest.net measures bandwidth and rudimentary latency, it is by no means a gauge of speed. Honestly, mtr is a really good tool to check latency and loss at all hops over an extended period of time. It isn't the most sophisticated method, but it can tell you enough. If you could be more specific as to what you want to capture, then I'm sure we can be more helpful at suggesting a specific tool or method.

Comment: I'm looking to get the same measurements speedtest.net gives but in an automated fashion I can run in the background periodically.

Comment: updated the question; hopefully its clearer now.

Comment: ping using .1 interval and 1000 count and standard iperf should get you what you need. Setup a server elsewhere (for iperf) and loop them in a bash script with output directed at a log file somewhere.

Comment: I'd like to avoid having to setup my own server -- I was hoping there was some automated way to test against one of the existing servers (speedtest.net for example).

Comment: I asked a similar question over [here](http://superuser.com/questions/388809/seeking-tool-to-automatically-collect-internet-broadband-speed-metrics-over-ti). I didn't get a satisfactory answer, but maybe you'll find some useful info among the answers.

Answer (score 1):

### Command line interface for testing internet bandwidth using speedtest.net.

https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli

**speedtest-cli** works with Python 2.4-3.4

```
wget -O speedtest-cli https://raw.github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest_cli.py

chmod +x speedtest-cli


$ speedtest-cli -h<br>
usage: speedtest-cli [-h] [--bytes] [--share] [--simple] [--list]<br>
                     [--server SERVER] [--mini MINI] [--source SOURCE]<br>
                     [--version]<br>
```

optional arguments:

```
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit<br>
  --bytes          Display values in bytes instead of bits. Does not affect<br>
                   the image generated by --share<br>
  --share          Generate and provide a URL to the speedtest.net share<br>
                   results image<br>
  --simple         Suppress verbose output, only show basic information<br>
  --list           Display a list of speedtest.net servers sorted by distance<br>
  --server SERVER  Specify a server ID to test against<br>
  --mini MINI      URL of the Speedtest Mini server<br>
  --source SOURCE  Source IP address to bind to<br>
  --version        Show the version number and exit<br>
```

Comment: wow!  that looks really nice, I'll give that a try.